# MultipartUpload upload on S3 with AWS ios SDK

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-ios, awss3transfermanager

I want to upload large files on S3. I know there is an option multipart upload by which I can upload large file in parts. I read the documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html) but didn't find any code for the multipart upload. I have successfully uploaded a file on server as a single file but I want to use multipart for large file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IF you're still looking for a solution, you can check out my blog post on this subject: [Taming the AWS framework to upload a large file to S3](http://www.mobdesignapps.fr/blog/2016/10/26/uploading-large-file-to-aws-s3-in-the-background?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=response&utm_campaign=awareness). For large files you will have to skip using the AWSTransferManager as it uses cognito credentials which are limited to an hour validity.

Comment: Thanks for your blog post! I've commented regarding missing variable definitions.

Comment: otusweb I also need uploads in background.

Comment: @otusweb Very useful post! Do you have  any updates on the missing variable definitions or a more precise explanation?

Comment: @cronenberg. I have not updated the post. To be honest, most of the issue I have seen so far have been with the AWS configuration, it's a pain to figure out and get the failure reason from AWS. I'll probably write a more complete post in the near future, but I don't have a timeline yet.